# Azure Logic App: workflows not found and timer executed 15 minutes prior to expected execution

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using the new tier of logic apps that enable multiple workflow per logic app. I have observed two problems.

- My timer based trigger is scheduled to run on 10:30 but is executed at 10:15 (consistently). Other triggers that are also expected to run on the 30th minute of an hour also execute on the 15th minute of the hour. Is there any reason?
- I have currently deployed 6 workflows in my logic app. However, for 3 of the 6 the portal do not show the previous runs (meaning, I do not see the whole section that should be there, not even an empty table) nor do they actually trigger. (Two of them are now disabled but the third is a timer based trigger that should run but does not.) What I have found in application insights is that whenever I go in the portal and click on these workflows, the underlying storage operation returns a 404 error. This means to me that the workflow is not found. What is odd then is that the workflow itself shows in the portal. But when I click on the workflow, I only see the general information but no previous runs and no workflow URL.

I am deploying in the D1 tier using Bicep templates and the workflows itself are deployed using Azure DevOps as a ZIP.

This seems to me like an underlying platform issue.

Thanks

Alexander

PS: I tried posting this on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/) but it will not let me (I get a strange error and lose my question text). It has been the worst UX ever on a question platform so far for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: I had a incorrectly configured workflow as part of the Logic App. What was odd is that there was no validation error when I was saving this workflow even when I saved it in the portal.

If you want to check whether you also have such an error, restart your Logic App, go to Application Insights, select the Transaction search and wait a few minutes for the logs of the restart to get ingested into AI.

Then, you can look for the startup logs of your Logic App. As part of these, you will find any information about possible errors in your workflow configuration.